# Delete multiple records in subform

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

In Access 2007, I have a main form and a subform datasheet. I have a delete record button for the subform on the main form. I can obtain SelTop and SelHeight (via global variables) when the user selects several records in the subform for deletion.

In the OnClick function on the delete button I have the code

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

With the code like this the DoCmd will only delete one record. If I remove the warnings, DoCmd puts up its own warning but then deletes all the selected records.

Is this a feature in Access or some error I've committed? (The latter wouldn't surprise me, I'm going square-eyed through coding all day.)

I don't want to use the default DoCmd message, as I want to provide other information to the user at the same time.

If this behaviour is a quirk in Access, how do I delete multiple records in the subform? I've searched everywhere but can find no useful help.

Comment: When I have needed to delete multiple records, I have used a checkbox field, and then a delete query that removes any records where the box is checked.

Comment: That would certainly be a good way to do it, so ignoring or losing the record selectors. Think laterally!